# Python Selenium WebDriverWait two conditions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

After a page is loaded, there will be two outcomes, either one of the following div class will be present.

1. `css-can-click`
2. `css-donot-click`

If `css-can-click` is present, then I want to click on that `div`

If `css-donot-click` is present, then I will not click on the `div`, and will just skip the rest of the codes.

I am trying to use WebDriverWait to wait until either div class is present.

The following is a partial of my codes:

```
driver.get(theURL)

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="css-can-click"]'))).click()
```

Until here, the code works well. But now, how do I put in the condition where the class `css-donot-click` is present?

Comment: Please always add a minimum of reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce and provide a solution.  If possible add the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wait for another element that appears in either cases on the web page and takes more time to load then the click or don't click buttons.
Then use an `if` statement

```
if (driver.findElement(By.yourLocator) != null) {
   driver.findElement(By.yourLocator).click;
}
else if (driver.findElement(By.yourLocatorNotClick) != null) {
   driver.findElement(By.yourLocator).click;
}
```

Something like this.

P.S. This is in Java language, you will have to translate it to Python :P